# Sql database query/structure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

In the situation pictured below/above.
I want to be able to query, what musicians are on a song and which songs a musician is on...

1. is this the correct model for this situation?
2. Do I just query the "SongMusicians" Table?

This is an assignment for university and am having trouble with the theory.

My initial thought was to just have the songId in the musician Table and visa versa. BUT have been told i need a "intermediary" table.

Any help would be amazing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks OK for a problem of that nature. The linking table between the two main tables, let a musician have multiple songs and a song have multiple musicians. If you didn't have it and you added a songid in table musician (the same logic applies if you put musicianid in songs) you would have to duplicate all the information for the musician every time he participated in a song. That's not good.

To get information about a Musician that is in a song or otherwise, you JOIN the tables through the linking table in order to find the desired information.

To get all the information about the Songs a Musician is in you do:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM songs s
INNER JOIN songmusicians sm ON sm.songid= s.songid
INNER JOIN musicians m ON sm.musicianid= m.musicianid
WHERE m.FirstName = 'Kurt' AND m.LastName = 'Kobain';
```

To get all the musicians that participated in a song you do:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM songs s
INNER JOIN songmusicians sm ON sm.songid= s.songid
INNER JOIN musicians m ON sm.musicianid= m.musicianid
WHERE s.songTitle = 'Smells like teen spirit';
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just to Clarify.. so when i have this structure, I query the two tables ( musicians and songs) not the intermediary table, which contains the list?
Haven't looked over the Innerjoin Slides yet :/
Sorry, i think i get it now. you have used the inner join so that you can search the by name rather than by musician id right?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it. I wanted to show you the query that would let you get the Musicians or Songs details. If you only care about the ids, you can simply query the Linking table.

Comment: I think I not getting the theory, but this EXACT query doesn't work when i cane the first name and surname for the actual names in my database. could you explain what i would need to change to make it actually work?

Comment: This works if you have the record for the song in table songs, you have the musician with firstName 'Kurt' and LastName = 'Kobain' and you have a linking table with the id of song and musician. Maybe you are doing something wrong along the process. Try creating an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with your tables and sample data and show me what is doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how I would go about creating a sqlfiddle (complete noob)

but this is the error I get

17:14:50 SELECT m.* FROM songs s INNER JOIN MusicianSongsIdsongmusicians sm ON sm.songsongidSongSongId = s.songidSongId INNER JOIN MusicianIdmusicians m ON sm.musiciansongidMusicianSongsId = MusicianIdm.musicianid WHERE SongTitles.songTitle = 'Song1' LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1146. Table 'newschema.musiciansongsidsongmusicians' doesn't exist 0.000 sec

Is it the tables and the data you need to see?

Comment: That error tells you that you are using wrong table names. And if your tables are called as you said in your question, these are very wrong indeed. :)

Comment: ok Sorry I have changed my names after first trying your query,

I have edited the image in my question ( not sure of the etiquette) to show my new names.

Sorry if that is more hassle for you, but i did try the original query..

Thanks

Comment: As far as i could see the only things you changed were the column names in the songmusicians table (right?). I edited my answer. Try one of those, and put the songTitle you want.

Comment: right, I also changed the Fk names to something sensible ( probably makes no difference here)
Thank you I will try now.

Comment: YES! Thank you!!! One issue was I had "surname" rather than "LastName"
Thank you! This site and its users are a godsend!

Comment: @user3075549. Glad you got it working. Make sure you take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site and start answering some questions too :)